# au.archive mirror is broken

Tags: mirrors

I'm wondering where do I go to check the status of and report problems to a mirror.

The au.archive mirror is down at the moment (I couldn't even connect to it about 30 minutes ago) with it directing to an aarnet webpage at the moment when trying to access it.

I assume some maintenance or such has caused issues, but I can't seem to find any sort of status webpages that relate to mirrors.

Comment: I don't think they intend you to navigate from the top with a browser; for example if you want to download 18.04 you can at http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/pub/ubuntu/releases/18.04/  (*not yet released so its still beta there*); if you want to update your system you can too http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/bionic/  *I just enabled it on my box; it worked fine:   Get:20 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]*

Comment: The only reason for navigating to the top level is to see if it was up (you do get an ftp directory structure if you do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a mirror is down by visiting [Down For Everyone Or Just Me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/), however there isn't a central website where you can select an Ubuntu mirror from a list of mirrors and check the status and report problems with that mirror. Report the issue to the mirror that is down or else either wait for the mirror to come back up or temporarily use a different mirror.

Immediately after a new version of Ubuntu is released, Canonical temporarily adds more Ubuntu iso image servers, so that everyone who wants to download the newly released Ubuntu iso image can download it quickly.